# Center text and image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a block of text within a page and put a horizontally and vertically centered image inside the block of text. I don't want to use background-image.

This is what I got, but is not working at all.

```
<div style="font-family: Times; font-size: 12pt; width: 400px; position: absolute; z-index:20; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; top: 50px;">
    <img style="position: absolute; z-index:1; top: 20px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" src="MyImage.jpg" width="202" height="267" />
        <strong>This is my Text. Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        <br />
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        <br />
        Retrieved from:<br />
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        <br />
        Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
        <br />
</div>
```

Comment: You want the image to be behind the text, right?

Comment: Yes. The image behind the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read a article about this. To perfectly align the blocks use:

```
.Center-Container {
  position: relative;
}

.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

these css styles are the key ! check it out here:

```css
div {
  font-family: Times;
  font-size: 12pt;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 20;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
p {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  z-index: 1;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <p>
    B lah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
    Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah

    <br />
    <img src="MyImage.jpg" width="50" height="50" />
  </p>

</div>
```

You can read about this in here

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

**EDIT**

The img tag is now IN the p tag. you can check here [Should I put paragraph tags around images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151267/should-i-put-paragraph-tags-around-images) 
if thats a good idea.

Comment: The text is centered, but the image is not. I want the image centered within the text.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? i edited the snippet

Comment: Could you select my answer as the correct answer? :) so other people will know that this was the correct answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

position: relative;

instead of absolute
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hsBux

```
<div style="font-family: Times; font-size: 12pt; width: 400px; position: relative; z-index:20; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; top: 50px;">
<img style="position: absolute; z-index:1; top: 20px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" src="MyImage.jpg" width="202" height="267" />

 <strong>This is my Text. Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
    <br />
    Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
    <br />
    Retrieved from:<br />
    Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
    <br />
    Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
    <br />
 </div>
```

Comment: The image is at the left margin of the text. I want it centered horizontally and vertically from the text block.

Comment: Sorry didn't read it right. It seems like answer 2 should do the job. Goodluck